# Accessing the value of custom field in redmine plugin

Tags: ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins, redmine-api

I am using Redmine 2.1 and I am writing a custom plugin. I am trying to access the value of a custom field on an issue.

```
  def controller_issues_edit_before_save(context = {})
    issue = context[:issue]

    add_assignee(issue)
  end
```

I am getting my issue then I pass it to a custom function.

```
private
  def add_assignee(issue)
    add_watcher_to_issue(issue, issue.custom_field_values {'bob'})
  end
```

I don't seem able to get the value of my custom field `bob`. `bob` is a user field.

How do I get the value of my custom field?

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it myself but the argument passed to `issue.custom_field_values {'bob'}` confuses me. it looks like you pass a block?!

Looked at this [line](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.1-stable/app/models/issue.rb#L173) I think `custom_field_values` is a hash so pass an expected key:

```
issue.custom_field_values('bob')
```